# How to implement multicast sockets?

Tags: c#

How can I implement multicast sockets in C#? Any code snippet along with a simple explanation is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this site: http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=409

Comment: To be quite frank, I think this is a very poor question simply for being very general. 
You should study the problem yourself and then return with specific any questions. Your best chance to learn anything is to look it up yourself instead of asking others to explain it from the basics or look the resources up for you. This is also why I downvoted your question.

Comment: @Nubsis While I heartily agree with you, that approach seems to be frowned upon by the masses here. Helping people to learn is second to learning parrot-fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google it: http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=409

Comment: Damn! You beat me to it. I was 2 seconds from hitting the 'Post your answer' button with the exact same link. :)

Comment: Actually, I posted it as a comment only 14 seconds after you ;)
Then I figured, it's practically an answer.

Comment: Well, i'm the slowest anyway so. :)

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta: you're asking for a rather advanced concept. There's quite a lot written about it. If you haven't got a pretty strong understanding of networking already, try to just use the code, or read through some tutorials or books on the subject. Here's just another that Google brings incl. full source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/multicast.aspx

Comment: Apologies from my side to all of you.I will read by my self and understand.Thanks.

Comment: Is it required to give Target IP or it will broadcast to all?